# Story about a man who has alternating streaks of good luck and bad luck

Tags: story-identification

I remember reading a story, I think in the early nineties though it's probably a lot older than that, about a man who would have streaks of good luck, alternated with equal streaks of bad luck. So after a short streak of good luck, a short streak of bad luck would follow.
The story dealt for a large part about a huge streak of good luck in which, among other things, he won the lottery. Knowing that an extreme streak of bad luck is coming up,

> he tries to commit suicide--and fails, which is the first event in his new streak of bad luck.

I think it was a short story, not a novel(la). It may or may not have been written by Harry Harrison.

Does anyone know what it's called, and where I can find it?

Comment: I know this might not be what you are looking for, but Gladstone Gander from the Donald Duck universe is actually a more interesting character than some might think.

He has a constant string of luck throughout his endeavors, except on his birthday, when he has a karma-like opposite 24 hours.

Comment: DS9 did an episode on this premise

Comment: And of course, there's the "Bundy curse": http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zMYge-cCw4&feature=youtube_gdata_player

Comment: The alternating streaks of good and bad luck are reminiscent of Michael Fessier's ["The Man in the Black Hat"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?75472) but not the attempted suicide. I'm pretty sure that's not the story we're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Spider Robinson's [Callahan's Place](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callahan%27s_Place) stories have a recurring character similar to this.  His nickname is the Lucky Duck, though the luck tends to happen to the people *around* him.

Comment: I looked at the wikipedia page, but it doesn't really match my recollections of the story. I remember the setting as a normal world, where the only thing out of the ordinary was the streaks of good/bad luck of the main character. Thanks though! Maybe I should check out these novels regardless :).

Comment: you totally should, those books are so much fun!!

Comment: It's not the Duck; he never tries to commit suicide, and is only a side character (or, arguable, part of the ensemble cast for several of the novels) -- it's still a good series to read, though.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds quite similar to a Spanish film called [Intacto / Intact](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0220580/) in which luck is treated as a commodity that can be stolen.
They could be linked in some way?